# How to store dynamically values in array using XSLT and make comparision of values?

Tags: xslt

I am again providing you the requirement like this.
Could you please look into this?

```
<xml>
<test>
<BookID>
  <BookID1>
    <BookID2>
      0061AB
    </BookID2>
  </BookID1>
</BookID>
<amount>
  16
</amount>
</test>
<test>
<BookID>
  <BookID1>
    <BookID2>
      0062CD
    </BookID2>
  </BookID1>
</BookID>
<amount>
  2
</amount>
</test>
<test>
<BookID>
  <BookID1>
    <BookID2>
      0061AB
    </BookID2>
  </BookID1>
</BookID>
<amount>
  2
</amount>
</test>
</xml>
```

here According to the equal value of BookID, I want to add the amount value.....like for above example, if value of BookID is 0061AB, then the value of amount should be 18.

**Edit** (Pasted to Answer)

*Output should be like this*

```
<xml>
  <test>
    <BookID>
      <BookID1>
        <BookID2>
          0061AB
        </BookID2>
      <BookID1>
    </BookID>
    <amount>
      18
    </amount>
  </test>
  <test>
    <BookID>
      <BookID1>
        <BookID2>
          0062CD
        </BookID2>
      <BookID1>
    </BookID>
    <amount>
      2
    </amount>
  </test>
</xml>
```

Comment: Dipta - please don't try to edit answers with new information - Use the comments to interact with answerers. Also, please try to take the time to provide all relevant information in your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the sum of the amounts. You can do with with xpath like the below

```
  <xsl:template match="/xml">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(test[normalize-space(BookID)='0061AB']/amount)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

**Edit**

You can parameterize the BookID by using a variable, or by using a call-template as per my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728888/how-to-store-dynamically-values-in-array-using-xslt-and-make-comparison-of-value#12739834)

The following stylesheet

```
  <xsl:template match="/xml">
    <xsl:variable name="bookID" select="'0061AB'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(test[normalize-space(BookID)=$bookID]/amount)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

**Edit #2**

It seems that you are now after [grouping distinct elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153156/xslt-how-to-count-distinct-values-in-a-node) and aggregating the totals.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- the identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="test">
        <xsl:variable name="bookID" select="normalize-space(BookID/text())" />
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::test[normalize-space(BookID/text())=$bookID])">
            <test>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </test>
        </xsl:if>
        <!--Else `eat` the duplicate test node-->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="amount">
        <amount>
            <xsl:variable name="bookID" select="normalize-space(../BookID/text())" />
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(//test[normalize-space(BookID/text())=$bookID]/amount)"/>
        </amount>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces the output

```
<xml>
    <test>
        <BookID>
            0061AB
        </BookID>
        <amount>18</amount>
    </test>
    <test>
        <BookID>
            0062CD
        </BookID>
        <amount>2</amount>
    </test>

</xml>
```

Please can you take the time to read through the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

**Edit 3**

This stylesheet will meet your latest requirement.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <!-- the identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="test">
        <xsl:variable name="bookID" select="normalize-space(BookID/BookID1/BookID2/text())" />
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::test[normalize-space(BookID/BookID1/BookID2/text())=$bookID])">
            <test>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </test>
        </xsl:if>
        <!--Else `eat` the duplicate test node-->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="amount">
        <amount>
            <xsl:variable name="bookID" select="normalize-space(../BookID/BookID1/BookID2/text())" />
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(//test[normalize-space(BookID/BookID1/BookID2/text())=$bookID]/amount)"/>
        </amount>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: (Comment from Dipta)Thanks for you r post. Here the BookID value comming dynamically and I need to check for equal BookID value and i need to add the amount of the equal BookID. Would this logic work for this or any change is needed for the above logic?

Comment: Actually i am not much familar with this site.So this kind of mistake happenned.Please ignore it

Comment: okay.....I am implementing the logic in my xsl that you have suggesting me....thnx

Comment: @Dipta A common way of grouping is to exclude nodes which have the same key as one which has been previously processed, i.e. if you look above, you will see `not(preceding-sibling::{Test for Duplication here})`

Comment: @nonb..yes it is answer of this question.

Comment: @nonnb....Could you please look into this? i am providing you another requirement.

Comment: @Dipta I've answered 2 questions, and you haven't upvoted or marked either as answered, so as it stands, there is little incentive for me to answer your questions.

Comment: I don't know how to mark it as answer. previously I have also told you that I am not much familar with the site.If you tell me the way how to mark it as answer,then I can do that. I have also mentioned in my comment those as answer. thanks

Comment: @Dipta - Updated again. Note that this isn't really the way that StackOverflow works - ideally you should get your question ready + right first time, and then if post new questions when you have a new requirement. You should also give your best effort to attempting this yourself - this is the best way to learn new technologies.

Comment: Thanks for your information.This really worked.I will keep in mind further.Thanks again